# Error during changing status from login to logout

Tags: php

everyone .. I am facing an small error and i am unable to fix it. Please help show me some direction over it.
Here i wan to change the status of login to logout after soemone login. but it doesn't change its status to logout.

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
session_start();
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/dandelion/index.php'){
   $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?con=9';
   header('Location: ' .$url);
}elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/dandelion/'){
   $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'index.php?con=9';
   header('Location: ' .$url);
}
?>
<html>
  <body>



      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="margin-top: 70px; height: 1px;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
            <li><a href="index.php?con=1"><b>Hem</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?con=2"><b>Om Oss</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?con=3"><b>Boendet</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?con=4"><b>V&aring;rt Arbete</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?con=5"><b>V&aring;ld i n&auml;ra relation</b></a></li>
            <li ><a href="index.php?con=6"><b>Kontakt</b></a></li>
            <li>
                 <?php
                 if($user_name == NULL){
                   ?>
                   <a class="login" href="index.php?con=7" rel="nofollow" title="Logga in p&aring; ditt kundkonto">
                      <b>Logga in</b>
                   </a>
                     <?php
                       } else {
                      ?>
                       <a class="login" href="php/logout.php" title="Logga in p&aring; ditt kundkonto">
                      <b>logga ut</b>
                       </a>
                     <?php
                       }
                     ?>
           </li>
          </ul>
          <script>

               var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');

          </script>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here my "logout.php" file.

```
<?php
 //session_unset($_SESSION['login_user_name']);
 session_start();
 session_destroy();
 header('Location:../index.php?con=1');
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you put `echo "logout";exit;` into you logout.php to see if it actually gets called? Please enable your error_reporting and display_errors

Comment: @Philipp i think its not calling... any  way to fix it ?

Comment: try, if(strlen($user_name)> 0) {...} in the place of if($user_name == NULL){..}

Comment: You have to put the correct URL into the href of your link

Comment: @DhavalDave it worked but after that in place pf login ...logout is enabled even if i refresh it.

Comment: @Philipp those links are correct links as per my files i stored.